# How to extend dataframe to length of list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I'm using a code to update my column using a list. It works as long as the list length shorter than the df index, since I'm using a workaround code by updating the column by using pd.series. Here's what I mean below.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['a' , 'Hello'],
    ['b', 'Hi There'],
    ['c', 'Hola'],
    ['d']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ColA', 'ColB'])

temp = list(df['ColB'].dropna())
temp.append('Sup')
temp.append('Chao')
df['ColB'] = pd.Series(temp)

print(temp)

df
```

The output:

```py
['Hello', 'Hi There', 'Hola', 'Sup', 'Chao']

Out[1]:
    ColA    ColB
0   a       Hello
1   b       Hi There
2   c       Hola
3   d       Sup
```

There are 5 elements in the list, but since the original frame is of index length 4, it does not include the last element 'Chao'.

Comment: That's because there is no corresponding entry in colA, like say 'e'. If there were, it would have taken it. By default pandas won't like to include NaNs and nulls into rows to make space for new column values.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do, whats the reason you want to append one value to a dataframe? This does not make much sense

Answer (score 0):

```
col = 'ColB'
temp = list(df[col].dropna())
df = df.drop(columns= col )
temp.append('Sup')
temp.append('Chao')
pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(temp).rename(columns ={0:'ColB'})], axis=1 )

ColA    ColB
0   a   Hello
1   b   Hi There
2   c   Hola
3   d   Sup
4   NaN Chao
```

This is probably inefficient, but you can drop the col, append the list, and then use concat while renaming the column back to the original name.